# Why can’t I boot from external HDD?

Tags: opensuse, bootable-media

I have `OpenSUSE live iso` downloaded.

I have a 16GB USB stick & a 1TB external HDD.

I wrote the ISO to the USB stick and the external HDD using **Win32DiskImager**.

When I restart my computer, I can see my USB stick in the BIOS boot menu and I can boot it.  However, I can't see my external drive.

I tried everything & every tool (*UnetBootIn,SUSE Studio Image Writer, ImageUSB etc.*), but I can't make my external HDD bootable.

My external HDD works without any problem. It's not damaged in any way.

Answer (score 0):

That is a limitation/configuration problem in your BIOS. It has nothing to do with the Linux distro.

That said, you probably don't want to write the live image to the external drive as that would be a waste of space. Instead, write the image to USB and boot from there, then once you're running the live environment, follow the steps to do a native (non-live) install to your external drive.